# Knockout Reason for if-binding not working when updated

Tags: knockout.js, signalr

I'm working all day on a problem that is driving me insane. It seems like the contents of a knockout 'if' statement is not re-evaluated when its value is updated.

I have a viewModel like so:

```
var userViewModel = (function(){
    var context = ko.observable(),

    // SignalR hub
    hub = $.connection.user;

    hub.client.setContext = function(data){
        context(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
    }

    return {
        context: context;
    };
})();
```

It uses SignalR to update a viewModel in the client, which does not yet exist in on start-up.

I'm using a ko if binding so the view will not break down when applying the binding. The view lookes like this:

```
<div class="js-user-template">
<!-- ko if: context -->
    <div data-bind="with: context">
        <span data-bind="text: firstName"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: lastName"></span>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

The binding sauce to put it al together:

```
$('.js-user-template').each(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(userViewModel, this);
});
```

When a SignalR updates the client asynchronously using setContext it's not updated in the DOM. The weird thing is, it does work about 10% of the time, which indicates a timing/threading issue. No warnings of any kind are logged in the console.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can reproduce this in jsFiddle with something like a setTimeout/setInterval instead of the hub code? Looks okay to me. You don't actually need the extra `if`, as `with` already handles null/undefined properly.

Comment: Why is the ApplyBindings in an each loop?

Comment: I tried to make this a jsfiddle and took out signalr and mapping plugin.  seems to work for me http://jsfiddle.net/drdamour/L9FAa/

Comment: Thanks for your comments everyone. Found the problem and answered my own question. Thanks for pointing me to JSFiddle, i will use that in the future. BeaverProj, I do the apply bindings in a loop because my page can have more then one 'js-user-template' on a page.

Answer (score 0):

Gentleman, thanks for you're help! After a good night sleep and you guys telling me that this *should* work, i found the problem.

My binding sauce actually looked more like this:

```
myNS.bindUserTemplate = function(context){
  $('.js-user-template').each(function(){
      ko.applyBindings(userViewModel, this);
  });
}

myNS.DomUpdated(myNS.bindUserTemplate);.
```

Or own little framework lets me bind to a custom event everytime something is updated in the DOM. This way I can parse it and see if it contains templates. My problem was that i forgot to select the .js-user-template class in the context of the updated element. This resulted in the templated being bound 4 times, instead of one....

Sorry for wasting your time, hopefully this question can still help someone with the same kind of problem.